# `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir when trying to make a new Rails project on macOS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to start a new rails application on my MacBook Pro, but when I execute `rails new myApp` my machine tells me Permission Denied? I am an administrator on my machine so it should be allowing me to CRUD files. Is this normal on macOS?

Comment: could you paste the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

You may be lacking write permissions in the folder where you are running `rails new` command.

In that folder simply try running `mkdir test_folder`
If this also fails then go one level up and check permissions of that folder where you want to create new application.
Make sure to have Write permissions on that folder.
You can use `chmod` to change permissions.

```
chmod projects
cd projects
rails new my_app
```